# How to use Google Directions API V3 to get travel time in Android app

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm very much a beginner in terms of Android programming and the Google Maps API.

I would like to be able to fetch the estimated travel time between two locations and display that information in my app. For instance, the user puts in their address and a destination address, and the app gets the time between them. I want to be able to do other calculations with the time later, so it's not an option to just direct the user to the Maps app.

There are some great responses elsewhere on the site on how to do this with V2 of the API, but I couldn't seem to find one that would help me with V3.

Secondly, am I allowed to display travel time without a map? I'm having trouble understanding Google's regulations on this point. Certain aspects of the API are not allowed to be used without a mapView... but which ones?

***EDIT: managed to accomplish the first part using the http service and a returned json object as detailed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237290/json-parsing-of-google-maps-api-in-android-app).*** Still don't have an answer to the second part of the question about Google's TOS.

Comment: Bonus question: if it is possible to get an estimated duration to a location, does that duration include traffic? Is there a way to make it so?